# For whom is stackoverflow.blog

Tags: discussion, blog

Is the blog for users of Stack Overflow? I guess it's not, because I'd prefer to read meta posts, write comments, up-/down-vote, etc.

So for whom is the blog? Who are those mysterious people who need to be officially announced with new feature, e.g. [custom filters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters), while [it was already available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/299295) for a month.

Comment: Are you referring to [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1)? That's still featured on Meta, just go to the main site and there is a link in the box on the right side that will take you to MSE. The blog will be used for announcements by the company and there is nothing anyone could change about that. I don't see how you would "shut this crap down", can you elaborate? (And possibly rephrase that a bit nicer? Everyone is angry on both sides, no need to fuel the fire further.)

Comment: _So for whom is blog?_ For Stackoverflow users

Comment: Most companies have a blog today. It’s their public face to the world, as an entity. It’s used for company announcements, to demonstrate SME, for PR, partnerships, SEO, etc. Also, I don’t know you, but I’m guessing you’re not in a position to “shut this crap down”, regardless of whatever answers or comments you get here. So this Meta-Q seems kinda pointless to me?

Comment: I recommend you to spend less time reading sites that annoy you instead of making futile efforts to shut them down. You'll be happier that way.

Comment: @yivi, I am not complaining about content, it's sometimes really nice to read. I am only complaining about posting it there and not here. What annoys me: no votes, no comments, no authentication (random guy can use my or your name), too strong moderation (it's done by employees).

Comment: @Secespitus, thanks for link, forgot that this change was made for the whole stack exchange network.

Comment: One reason communication is moving from meta to the blog is that employees do not wish to interact on meta due to the volume and tone of negative feedback, and the company is not forcing them to. There's a discussion open about that.

Comment: And one of the official reason is that meta is not build for annoncement. With voting system based on tag. Meta is kinda a bug tracker. Blog is the public annoncement face to the world. They don't want post to be closed on meta as it will cut the discussion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, the blog is not just for users of the site Stack Overflow. It is for the broadest possible group of visitors having an interest in the company Stack Overflow. So that is users. non-users, Google-ers, Bing-ers, investors, corporate entities, you name it.

Due to that target group it won't be shut down, no matter what your, mine or the whole Meta opinion is.

Comment: In fact, the blog is the specific designated preferred communication medium over meta.

Comment: So blog pursues no interests to make me feel comfortably there, it's completely different thing. It's awful thing for me. But it could be good for those 42 man from world (or how many visitors there are not from SO?) and it's worth all the effort.. mmm.. google you say? google finds me answers, not blog entries.

Comment: Btw, [custom filters article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters/) is undoubtedly the most entertaining article for non-SO users (sarcasm). Yet, it's posted there and not here.

Comment: @Sinatr Communication, Sales and Marketing are disciplines that require highly skilled employees. I seldom meet software engineers that I would trust with any communication let alone the communication deemed critical for my company. I certainly can't and won't judge if the content on the blog is fit for purpose. Beyond my league and pay grade.

Answer (score -4):

[@Rene’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387817/2562182) is correct: Most companies have a blog today. It’s their public face to the world, as an entity.

It’s used for company announcements, to demonstrate SME, for PR, partnerships, SEO, etc.

Given many recent events, I’m guessing in a few months’ time, SE is going to announce some major changes to Meta, and repurpose or refocus the site.

One of the things I’m speculating they’re going to do is move *all* company announcements to the blog (and move bug reports and feature requests to a dedicated system like Jira, etc).

But even if that never happens, if you want to stay abreast of SO the company, you’ll have to follow the blog, like any other company out there.

Having said that: if it helps, I was reading the blog earlier today, and I came across this post:

[Making Sense of the Metadata: Clustering 4,000 Stack Overflow tags with BigQuery k-means](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/24/making-sense-of-the-metadata-clustering-4000-stack-overflow-tags-with-bigquery-k-means/)

Which is somewhat interesting in its own right¹, but also meta-interesting in that its demonstrable interest is in marketing Google BigQuery to developers. Evangelism. Which tells me that SO is expecting that developers and data scientists are reading their blog.

That is, the blog is aimed (at least partially) at *us*.

---

<sub>1: Much more interesting *as content* was this off-site blog that one linked to: [Predicting when StackOverflow will reply](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-will-stack-overflow-reply-how-to-predict-with-bigquery-553c24b546a3).

***This*** is the kind of analysis I’d like to see in the next Meta post about *Data science time!*. For example, what the heck is going on in [this graph of account age vs answer rate?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvoad.png)</sub>