# Why idea of contributing as a huge community to a covid-19 related researches is bad?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397223/should-we-identify-covid-19-related-programming-questions-if-so-how) which gets more and more downvoted. And I am trying to understand why this happens.

- Is it because some people already tried to create annoying tags ([[covid-19]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394683/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-tag), [[covid-19-data]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-data-tag))?
- Is it because this topic is in every news and people already hate talking about it?

I am just thinking: why can't the Stack Overflow community with all its theoretical man-power contribute to the topic: maybe finding cure, maybe some investigations, maybe some things important for doctors?

I am a complete noob in research or programming in medicine facility, but if my friend virologist (I don't have one) would ask me to write a little software for him in the name of humanity - I'd probably do.

Why don't we?

I've no idea how to organize it. I agree tags are the wrong approach. Maybe a user has to pass verification that he is related to research somehow and then his questions are automatically highlighted to indicate their high priority in a dedicated way similar to bounties? Something else?

Comment: @yivi, in other words if I want to contribute I have to actively search for *another way*? Finding some *other* forum? But *not here*?

Comment: As yivi said, the problem are not the questions that arise from covid-19 (as long as they are on-topic) but the organisation of it. I would like it if SO (the company) joins the effort and maybe creates a free team instance to coordinate that research. I don't think it should be done directly on SO (the site) because there are no tools for it and we might have to to a big cleanup in a couple of month/years.

Comment: [SO blogged about ways to help a while back...](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/26/ways-to-help-the-fight-against-covid-19-from-home/)

Comment: As much of a serious matter the current pandemic is, there is _very little_ that is actionable from the platform's perspective. Related proposals were not good so far, such as this [deleted meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396556/more-tolerance-needed-for-low-quality-questions-during-covid-19) suggesting us to be more tolerant to low quality content.

Comment: COVID-19 is a pandemic, not a programming topic. It's being discussed on the news enough, why discuss it even more and spread panic? It makes no sense.

Comment: My undergrad education was in virology. Wanna be my friend? :-)

Comment: @TheMaker Eh, I don't think anyone's going to panic over "How to normalize a dataframe" just because the data is about the virus.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I [don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387816/1997232) read SO blogs. They are poor pages targeting some other people. If any [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311601/299295) was not made on meta - I haven't read it.

Comment: @CodyGray, of course! Who don't want to have C# expert as a friend ;)

Comment: Well, you asked why SO wasn't doing anything to help, and I pointed out that they were. Perhaps SO is doing something but you don't know about it?

Comment: @BSMP But I feel it t still is a bade idea

Answer (score 40):

Organizing as a community to contribute is not bad idea per se; but the Q&A site is a bad place to attempt said *organization*.

It is simply not built for that. Would suck at it, and in the process harm the actual use-case of the site.

The site is fine to store **good, useful on-topic questions**. But to *"organize research efforts about a subject matter that's mostly orthogonal to topics on this site"*? Not so good.

Better do the "organizing" somewhere else. There are SO resources that can still be used. Chat, for example. Good, on-topic questions related to COVID-19 research can be posted and answered. Many of them in network sites where the questions would be much more appropriate. Etc.

Comment: Indeed; it would be like using a grocery store as an HQ for planning and overseeing logistics of maximizing farm crop yield... sure it's related vaguely to a grocery store in that it's about food for people, but it's not at all the appropriate place to do such a thing. People come to the grocery store to buy groceries, not to plan or oversee farm crop yield.

Answer (score 18):

> I am just thinking: why can't SO community with all its theoretical man-power contribute to the topic: maybe finding cure, maybe some investigations, maybe some things important for doctors?

This isn't the profession of many of the people that come to Stack Overflow.  Nor is it the *reason* that people come to Stack Overflow.

I stated in that question you linked that [we really do not care](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397223/should-we-identify-covid-19-related-programming-questions-if-so-how#comment768812_397224) what the subject material is that someone is asking a question on, so long as that question is on-topic.  Contextualizing it to be about Covid-19 is no different than contextualizing it about cancer, or actuarial tables, or financial impacts, from the perspective of software designed to crunch numbers about A Thing™ and produce a result.

Furthermore, **we're volunteers.**  We all have day jobs or other things that preoccupy our time.  If we want to volunteer to help the cause, then that's on us as individuals, and I'm certain that if we wanted to do so we could find places to want to volunteer.

[Oh look, the blog post does actually cover some places where people are gathering and discussing where to volunteer online.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/26/ways-to-help-the-fight-against-covid-19-from-home/) Can't vouch for any of them personally, though.

I suppose my perspective is simple.

## I'm delighted that you want to help out with the pandemic, but if it isn't about programming, it's *still* not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wait, so, are you saying that it needs to be about programming in order to be on topic? What about my burning questions about making delicious tapioca pudding? You're saying I need to ask about a *program* that will make tapioca pudding?

Comment: @CodyGray I feel like *we* would need to ask *you* for help if you had a program that made tapioca pudding... :D

Comment: A program to make tapioca pudding?  PHP,  right?

Comment: Of course all questions have to be on topic and about programming. As you say, we are volunteers, to me it doesn't matter help this guy or another guy. I am choosing subjectively. But if there 1) ontopic 2) programming question 3) from a guy who does something related to covid-19 directly or indirectly, then I could really choose him. A little help I or you could offer multiplied by the number of us will make a difference I think. Currently I am not contributing. But I could if there would be an easy way. If someone would organize it for me. It may be I am completely useless, but you are not.

Comment: @Sinatr:  I'm being explicit here.  If you want to help here on Stack Overflow, answering on-topic questions is plenty.  If those on-topic questions *also* happen to be about the current pandemic, then that's extra brownie points.  I remain adamant that this site **is not about solving the pandemic**, and we are not in the business of organizing any kind of team to help solve said pandemic.

Answer (score 7):

Looking for existing organizations that are knowledgeable in this area and giving them the help their experts are asking for is much more useful than everyone trying to come up with their own solution for providing assistance. It's also more straight forward than Stack Overflow attempting to verify that a question is coming from a researcher at a university and not just some random person with a random idea.

That said, you could always still:

- Add a bounty to good questions that happen to be COVID-19 related.
- Encourage open source projects being used for COVID-19 research to [create a community
  ad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394409/open-source-advertising-1h-2020)
  so that people here see it.
- Make it a point to search for keywords like covid or coronavirus to prioritize those questions.

Comment: *"search for keywords like covid or coronavirus to prioritize those questions"* - this is the problem. Everybody can use such words. And I am not able to check. "Assume good intent" they said. "In the internet?" I ask. If SO team would do first steps, organize it for us... ok, ok. I am lazy. That's true.

Comment: @Sinatr Well, that just brings it back to looking to existing organizations that we know are doing the work: universities, hospitals, etc. If you think the blog post Makoto's answer links to is something SO should keep updating, that might be something they're willing to do. But I don't think SO should be trying to make users *prove* they're doing pandemic work. For one thing, many people mentioning COVID-19 in their questions aren't even making that claim.

Answer (score -3):

I completely agree with your proposal:

> Why can't the Stack Overflow community with all its theoretical man-power contribute to the topic: maybe finding cure, maybe some investigations, maybe some things important for doctors?

Or as @bdl said

> I would like it if SO (the company) joins the effort and maybe creates a **free team instance** to coordinate that research.

## No in stackoverflow.com

Maybe the **stackoverflow.com** itself is not the appropriate platform, but its popularity could help and I think some programmers who spend time on it, would 
be happy to help!

## What tools?

- Jira

  - To create issues or tasks
- Github organization

  - To create issues, tasks and of course code!

## Steps

- Contact to the researchers
- Register all problems or requirements as jira items or github issues:

  - mobile apps
  - ETLs
  - analytics
  - data procesing
  - artificial intelligence
  - cloud configurations
  - language translations
  - enterprise integrations, queues, rest apis, security
  - any topic in which a doctor, biologist or researcher could need help and stackoverflow programmers (c++, java, python, c#, nodejs, ruby, android, etc) want to contribute

## Contribution

Simple, just go to the issues backlog and try to solve them!